# Does Googlebot index closed HTML details element?

Tags: seo, html, googlebot

I have the following HTML **details** element that is closed by default.

```html
<details>
  <summary>Details</summary>
  <p>
    Something small enough to escape casual notice.
  </p>
</details>
```

Does search engines' robots, specifically, **googlebot** index the paragraph inside of it?

Comment: By "closed" I assume you mean that it requires a click for users to see the contents?

Comment: Yes!  It needs a click to be opened.  Enter also opens it if it is focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the fact that the content within an element is not hidden from users (only activation is required to view it), Googlebot will crawl this content and will probably index it if all the main content is not against Google policy.

However, because the content is removed/hidden from the direct download stream, Google may give this content a lower priority than content downloaded in the direct stream.